# Como impedir navegador de exibir alerta e reenviar informações anteriores?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Trabalho em uma aplicação WEB .aspx que grava dados no banco.
O problema é que após gravar esses dados e exibir uma informação de sucesso para o usuário, se faço um reload na página o navegador vai enviar as informações novamente para o servidor que novamente irá gravar no banco.
Como posso evitar isso?

[image: reenviar informações anteriores]

Comment: @PauloHDSousa, obrigado pela atenção mas isso não resolve o meu problema. Vou tentar ser mais claro, a mensagem acima aparece quando pressiono F5 no teclado após efetuar um SUBMIT para o SERVIDOR atráves do evento protected void Salvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){//comandos }, ou seja, esse evento é acionado a primeira vez quando clico nele, e a segunda vez quando pressiono o F5 e depois no botão REPETIR da mensagem acima, se eu clico no CANCELAR acontece o que eu quero, ou seja, a tela é exibida sem enviar os dados novamente ao servidor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

você pode verificar se é um postback, caso positivo você pode redirecionar para uma outra pagina

```
if(IsPostBack) {
Response.Redirect("https://pt.stackoverflow.com/");
} else {
//Salva dados.
}
```

Da uma olhada : http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx